# Rails Voting Site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting started building a site with Rails and I would like people to be able to vote certain things with the options of "yes" or "no" or "right" or "wrong".  I would also like there to be a running tally computed by percent (maybe below). Could someone tell me how I can add this functionality?

Thanks

Comment: What functionality? Calculating percents? That's just division.

Comment: Basically something like this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973264.aspx
I'm just trying to add a voting section to the site and I'm really sure how to do it.

Comment: What part are you specifically having issues with? How far have you got? (Otherwise this just looks like a write my application question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just finished up something similar.

If you'd like to see how other people have tackled this problem, just [search github](http://github.com/search?type=Repositories&language=rb&q=vote&repo=&langOverride=&x=29&y=24&start_value=1). There are 30 ruby repos.

I found [acts_as_voteable](http://github.com/inspiresynergy/acts_as_voteable/tree/master) the most helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Remember to build it in such a way that enforces: "one vote for one IP address". Other than that, it is straight forward and plain Mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

You should also take a look at 'counters' in the API, such that each vote has a value and the tallies are kept on the voted-on object (so it doesn't have to run a count every single time).